# Struts2 i18n conflict with two web app

Tags: java, struts2, internationalization

I'm developing two web-apps in java using Struts2 version 2.3... and I'm deploying those web-apps on Jboss eap 6.1.

For each web-app I've specified a different value for the propetry

```
"struts.custom.i18n.resources"
```

into the struts.xml, so the property files containing the internationalyzed strings are named differently for the two web-apps.

Now I'm encountering the following strange problem.
When the server starts the first web-app I access with the browser is displayed fine, the second web-app I access, no matter what is the first and which the second, is displayed without the labels are retrieved from the properties.

So for example if in one web-ap I have

```
<s:text name="login.username"/>
```

and in the i18n file I've login.username=Username, and for the second web app I've

```
<s:text name="my.label"/>
```

and in the second i18n file I've my.label=Hello, suppose that I access the first web-app for first, then in the first web-app I see on screen "Username" (correct), in the second we-app I see "my.label" (wrong) as if the properties file is not read for the second web app I access.
Have you any ideas about the reason of this behaviour? I don't know how to investigate it. I've searched on the web without much luck.

Comment: Which exact version of S2? Turn the `devMode` on, debug your app.

Comment: You can use `debug` tag to investigate some properties.

Comment: So you mean your two web apps are totally separated and have nothing in common?!